# In SQL, how can you "group by" in ranges?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have a table with a numeric column (lets call it "score").

I'd like to generate a table of counts, that shows how many times scores appeared in each range.

For example:

```
score range  | number of occurrences
-------------------------------------
   0-9       |        11
  10-19      |        14
  20-29      |         3
   ...       |       ...
```

In this example there were 11 rows with scores in the range of 0 to 9, 14 rows with scores in the range of 10 to 19, and 3 rows with scores in the range 20-29.

Is there an easy way to set this up?  What do you recommend?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Neither of the highest voted answers are correct on SQL Server 2000. Perhaps they were using a different version.

Here are the correct versions of both of them on SQL Server 2000.

```
select t.range as [score range], count(*) as [number of occurences]
from (
  select case  
    when score between 0 and 9 then ' 0- 9'
    when score between 10 and 19 then '10-19'
    else '20-99' end as range
  from scores) t
group by t.range
```

or

```
select t.range as [score range], count(*) as [number of occurrences]
from (
      select user_id,
         case when score >= 0 and score< 10 then '0-9'
         when score >= 10 and score< 20 then '10-19'
         else '20-99' end as range
     from scores) t
group by t.range
```

Comment: Can i aggregate another column as well (like group counts). say i wana aggregate the scholarship column for each score range. I tried, but not getting it right

Comment: Nice answer @Ron Tuffin, however when you have two ranges like 10-20 , 100-200, then the order does not work. you would have order like 10-20, 100-200,20-30 etc. Any tip for the order by?

Comment: @ZoHas it's a bit of a hack but this works: order by len(t.range),t.range

Comment: Better answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730380/need-count-of-range-in-sql-query

Comment: what if you have more than a thousand groups? will just add 1000 when statements?

Comment: If you still have syntax issues, check this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22491/how-do-i-calculate-count-for-a-range-without-needing-to-use-multiple-queries

Comment: what about 0 count for any defined range?

Answer (score 45):

An alternative approach would involve storing the ranges in a table, instead of embedding them in the query.  You would end up with a table, call it Ranges, that looks like this:

```
LowerLimit   UpperLimit   Range 
0              9          '0-9'
10            19          '10-19'
20            29          '20-29'
30            39          '30-39'
```

And a query that looks like this:

```
Select
   Range as [Score Range],
   Count(*) as [Number of Occurences]
from
   Ranges r inner join Scores s on s.Score between r.LowerLimit and r.UpperLimit
group by Range
```

This does mean setting up a table, but it would be easy to maintain when the desired ranges change.  No code changes necessary!

Comment: I asked a question on Database Administrators [Table Design For Patterned Data Using Variable Bucket Ranges](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94275/table-design-for-patterned-data-using-variable-bucket-ranges) which didn't get an answer, but I ended up designing a system which has the ranges you mentioned. Love this answer.

Comment: Great answer! Easy to read query and clear structure.

Answer (score 33):

I see answers here that won't work in SQL Server's syntax.  I would use:

```
select t.range as [score range], count(*) as [number of occurences]
from (
  select case 
    when score between  0 and  9 then ' 0-9 '
    when score between 10 and 19 then '10-19'
    when score between 20 and 29 then '20-29'
    ...
    else '90-99' end as range
  from scores) t
group by t.range
```

EDIT: see comments

Comment: It is possibly because of the version of SQLServer I am using but to get your example to work (I test things before I vote them up) I had to move 'score' from after the 'case' to after each 'when'.

Comment: You're right, and thanks for the correction.  Apparently when you put the variable after the keyword 'case', you can only do exact matches, not expressions.  I learn as much from answering questions as from asking them. :-)

Answer (score 31):

In postgres (where `||` is the string concatenation operator):

```
select (score/10)*10 || '-' || (score/10)*10+9 as scorerange, count(*)
from scores
group by score/10
order by 1
```

gives:

```
 scorerange | count 
------------+-------
 0-9        |    11
 10-19      |    14
 20-29      |     3
 30-39      |     2
```

### And here's how to do it in T-SQL:

```sql
DECLARE @traunch INT = 1000;

SELECT 
    CONCAT
    ( 
      FORMAT((score / @traunch) * @traunch, '###,000,000') 
      , ' - ' , 
      FORMAT((score / @traunch) * @traunch + @traunch - 1, '###,000,000') 
    ) as [Range]
  , FORMAT(MIN(score), 'N0') as [Min]
  , FORMAT(AVG(score), 'N0') as [Avg]
  , FORMAT(MAX(score), 'N0') as [Max]
  , FORMAT(COUNT(score), 'N0') as [Count]
  , FORMAT(SUM(score), 'N0') as [Sum]
FROM scores
GROUP BY score / @traunch
ORDER BY score / @traunch
```

[image]

Comment: This is a magnificent answer. Highly underrated!

Answer (score 13):

James Curran's answer was the most concise in my opinion, but the output wasn't correct. For SQL Server the simplest statement is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    [score range] = CAST((Score/10)*10 AS VARCHAR) + ' - ' + CAST((Score/10)*10+9 AS VARCHAR), 
    [number of occurrences] = COUNT(*)
FROM #Scores
GROUP BY Score/10
ORDER BY Score/10
```

This assumes a #Scores temporary table I used to test it, I just populated 100 rows with random number between 0 and 99.

Comment: Ah... There's the advantage of actually taking the time to create the table. (I used an existing table with too few rows over too small a range)

Answer (score 6):

```
select cast(score/10 as varchar) + '-' + cast(score/10+9 as varchar), 
       count(*)
from scores
group by score/10
```

Comment: I like this, but you have to fix up the ranges outside the query if you're going to display it.

Comment: In case you decide to fix your answer you need to change your score/10 on the first line to be (score/10)*10 for both of them otherwise you get 3 - 12 instead of 30-39 etc. As per my post below you could add an order by to get the results in the right order.

Answer (score 6):

This will allow you to not have to specify ranges, and should be SQL server agnostic. Math FTW!

```
SELECT CONCAT(range,'-',range+9), COUNT(range)
FROM (
  SELECT 
    score - (score % 10) as range
  FROM scores
)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
create table scores (
   user_id int,
   score int
)

select t.range as [score range], count(*) as [number of occurences]
from (
      select user_id,
         case when score >= 0 and score < 10 then '0-9'
         case when score >= 10 and score < 20 then '10-19'
         ...
         else '90-99' as range
     from scores) t
group by t.range
```

Comment: Thanks!  I tried this and the basic idea works great, although the syntax that I had to use is slightly different.  Only the first "case" keyword is needed and then after the last condition, before the "as range" you need the keyword "end".  Other than that, worked great- thanks!

Comment: this solution is immensely readable - the divide by 10 solutions the other folks have provided - with the utmost respect - seems a little too opaque.

Answer (score 4):

I would do this a little differently so that it scales without having to define every case:

```
select t.range as [score range], count(*) as [number of occurences]
from (
  select FLOOR(score/10) as range
  from scores) t
group by t.range
```

Not tested, but you get the idea...

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @RangeWidth int

set @RangeWidth = 10

select
   Floor(Score/@RangeWidth) as LowerBound,
   Floor(Score/@RangeWidth)+@RangeWidth as UpperBound,
   Count(*)
From
   ScoreTable
group by
   Floor(Score/@RangeWidth)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.blah as [score range], count(*) as [number of occurences]
from (
  select case 
    when score between  0 and  9 then ' 0-9 '
    when score between 10 and 19 then '10-19'
    when score between 20 and 29 then '20-29'
    ...
    else '90-99' end as blah
  from scores) t
group by t.blah
```

Make sure you use a word other than 'range' if you are in MySQL, or you will get an error for running the above example.

Answer (score 1):

Because the column being sorted on (`Range`) is a string, string/word sorting is used instead of numeric sorting.

As long as the strings have zeros to pad out the number lengths the sorting should still be semantically correct:

```
SELECT t.range AS ScoreRange,
       COUNT(*) AS NumberOfOccurrences
  FROM (SELECT CASE
                    WHEN score BETWEEN 0 AND 9 THEN '00-09'
                    WHEN score BETWEEN 10 AND 19 THEN '10-19'
                    ELSE '20-99'
               END AS Range
          FROM Scores) t
 GROUP BY t.Range
```

If the range is mixed, simply pad an extra zero:

```
SELECT t.range AS ScoreRange,
       COUNT(*) AS NumberOfOccurrences
  FROM (SELECT CASE
                    WHEN score BETWEEN 0 AND 9 THEN '000-009'
                    WHEN score BETWEEN 10 AND 19 THEN '010-019'
                    WHEN score BETWEEN 20 AND 99 THEN '020-099'
                    ELSE '100-999'
               END AS Range
          FROM Scores) t
 GROUP BY t.Range
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT (str(range) + "-" + str(range + 9) ) AS [Score range], COUNT(score) AS [number of occurances]
FROM (SELECT  score,  int(score / 10 ) * 10  AS range  FROM scoredata )  
GROUP BY range;
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you could add some explanation about how your query resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.range as score, count(*) as Count 
from (
      select UserId,
         case when isnull(score ,0) >= 0 and isnull(score ,0)< 5 then '0-5'
                when isnull(score ,0) >= 5 and isnull(score ,0)< 10 then '5-10'
                when isnull(score ,0) >= 10 and isnull(score ,0)< 15 then '10-15'
                when isnull(score ,0) >= 15 and isnull(score ,0)< 20 then '15-20'               
         else ' 20+' end as range
         ,case when isnull(score ,0) >= 0 and isnull(score ,0)< 5 then 1
                when isnull(score ,0) >= 5 and isnull(score ,0)< 10 then 2
                when isnull(score ,0) >= 10 and isnull(score ,0)< 15 then 3
                when isnull(score ,0) >= 15 and isnull(score ,0)< 20 then 4             
         else 5  end as pd
     from score table
     ) t

group by t.range,pd order by pd
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm here because i have similar question but i find the short answers wrong and the one with the continuous "case when" is to much work and seeing anything repetitive in my code hurts my eyes. So here is the solution

```
SELECT --MIN(score), MAX(score),
    [score range] = CAST(ROUND(score-5,-1)AS VARCHAR) + ' - ' + CAST((ROUND(score-5,-1)+10)AS VARCHAR),
    [number of occurrences] = COUNT(*)
FROM order
GROUP BY  CAST(ROUND(score-5,-1)AS VARCHAR) + ' - ' + CAST((ROUND(score-5,-1)+10)AS VARCHAR)
ORDER BY MIN(score)
```

Answer (score 0):

For PrestoSQL/Trino applying answer from Ken https://stackoverflow.com/a/232463/429476

```
select t.range, count(*) as "Number of Occurance", ROUND(AVG(fare_amount),2) as "Avg",
  ROUND(MAX(fare_amount),2) as "Max" ,ROUND(MIN(fare_amount),2) as "Min" 
from (
  select 
   case 
      when trip_distance between  0 and  9 then ' 0-9 '
      when trip_distance between 10 and 19 then '10-19'
      when trip_distance between 20 and 29 then '20-29'
      when trip_distance between 30 and 39 then '30-39'
      else '> 39' 
   end as range ,fare_amount 
  from nyc_in_parquet.tlc_yellow_trip_2022) t
  where fare_amount > 1 and fare_amount < 401092
group by t.range;

 range | Number of Occurance |  Avg   |  Max  | Min  
-------+---------------------+--------+-------+------
  0-9  |             2260865 |  10.28 | 720.0 | 1.11 
 30-39 |                1107 | 104.28 | 280.0 |  5.0 
 10-19 |              126136 |   43.8 | 413.5 |  2.0 
 > 39  |               42556 |  39.11 | 668.0 | 1.99 
 20-29 |               19133 |  58.62 | 250.0 |  2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS number_of_occurances,
  FLOOR(scores / 10) * 10 AS scores_in_range
FROM ScoreTable
GROUP BY scores_in_range
ORDER BY scores_in_range DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

SQL Standard defines `WIDTH_BUCKET( <expr> , <min_value> , <max_value> , <num_buckets>)` function:

```
SELECT WIDTH_BUCKET(score, 0, 50, 5) AS bucket_num, COUNT(*)
FROM tab
GROUP BY WIDTH_BUCKET(score, 0, 50, 5)
ORDER BY bucket_num;
```

For input:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(score INT);

INSERT INTO tab(score) VALUES (1),(2),(9),(10),(11),(22),(23),(41);
```

Output:

```
bucket_num  count
1   3
2   2
3   2
5   1
```

---

Human-readable bucket range:

```
SELECT CONCAT((WIDTH_BUCKET(score, 0, 50, 5)-1)*10, '-', WIDTH_BUCKET(score, 0, 50, 5)*10-1) AS bucket_num,
       COUNT(*)
FROM tab
GROUP BY CONCAT((WIDTH_BUCKET(score, 0, 50, 5)-1)*10, '-', WIDTH_BUCKET(score, 0, 50, 5)*10-1)
ORDER BY bucket_num;
```

Output:

```
bucket_num  count
0-9     3
10-19   2
20-29   2
40-49   1
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/LVwIRssL)**

---

[T612, Advanced OLAP operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_standards/ms-tsqliso02/f6109ecb-6712-40f1-9106-6e42e1da8fc1)

> Transact-SQL partially supports this feature. *Transact-SQL does not support the WIDTH_BUCKET*, PERCENT_RANK, and CUME_DIST functions or the WINDOW and FILTER clauses.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you're asking about keeping such things going...

Of course you'll invoke a full table scan for the queries and if the table containing the scores that need to be tallied (aggregations) is large you might want a better performing solution, you can create a secondary table and use rules, such as `on insert` - you might look into it.

Not all RDBMS engines have rules, though!