# SQL stament groups rows and calculate average

Tags: mysql

I am stuck with the following issue. I have 1 table that looks like this:

`````````````````````````````````
field_number.. Value  
````````````````````````````````  
1 ......................... 1  
2 ..........................1  
3 ......................... 2  
4 ..........................2
`````````````````````````````````

etc.

I want to group different fieldnumbers and have an average for the value column. So the output should be:

```
field_number................Value

name(1,2)......................   1..............       ((1+1)/2)

name(3,4)......................   2..............       ((2+2)/2)
```

I have checked previous questions but cannot find any question that covers this issue (I might search on the wrong keywords though). So if this has already been covered my appologies, but any help or a point to a previous answer would be appreciated.

** =============UPDATE=============  **

I went through your suggestions but did not get it right. So I am trying to be more specific. I almost have the result I want apart from the fact I want to have a fixed value in one of my columns. I have the following query:

```
Select 
Avg(wp_rg_lead_detail.value),
wp_rg_lead_detail.field_number,
From
wp_rg_lead_detail
Where
wp_rg_lead_detail.field_number In (15, 17, 24) A
UNION
Select
Avg(wp_rg_lead_detail.value),
wp_rg_lead_detail.field_number,
From
wp_rg_lead_detail
Where
wp_rg_lead_detail.field_number In (16, 108, 18)
```

etc.

This gives me a table with two columns

```
wp_rg_lead_detail.value................field_number
4.3 (average)..............................15 (first value of av calculation)
```

What I want is to change the field number (15 in this case) in a fixed value (text). What and how should I add this to the query?

Comment: please mark an answer..

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT avg(value) FROM table WHERE field_number in (1,2)
SELECT avg(value) FROM table WHERE field_number in (3,4)
```

Comment: Tnx for your quick reply. When I enter the first line it works. Adding the second line gives me an error: #42000You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT avg(value) FROM wp_rg_lead_detail WHERE field_number in (3,4)' at line 2. Additionally this query gives me 1 olumn. I need a second column with the name. e.g name(1,2).

Answer (score 1):

For a generalized answer.

```
SELECT CONCAT('name','(',GROUP_CONCAT(field_number),')') AS field_number,
AVG(Value) as Value
FROM table_name
group by table_name.`Value`
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tnx, I managed to get the result I want with the following query: Select
  Avg(wp_rg_lead_detail.value),
  wp_rg_lead_detail.field_number
From
  wp_rg_lead_detail
Where
  wp_rg_lead_detail.field_number In (15, 17, 24)
UNION
Select
  Avg(wp_rg_lead_detail.value),
  wp_rg_lead_detail.field_number
From
  wp_rg_lead_detail
Where
  wp_rg_lead_detail.field_number In (16, 108, 18)
etc. . Now I get two columns, one with 1 column with the averages and one column with one of the values. What I want is instead of one of the value in the second column just a fixed name.. is this possible?

Comment: of course it is possible.. What is your `fixed value`

Comment: I have edited the query, i misunderstood the question.. pls check

Answer (score 1):

If your table is really this simple, you can also get away with:

```
select distinct
   Value,
   count(Value) as '#'
from table_name
group by Value
```

If you acctually want to group by a range, than you can put the logic of the range in your grouping clause (see [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e4b0f/5))

```
select distinct
    avg(Value) as average,
   floor(Value),
   count(Value) as '#'
from table_name
group by floor(Value)
```

In the fiddle I used grouping on whole integers, but you can make that as complex as you like (see, for instance, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999421/group-by-price-range) example)

If you are actually also interested in your corresponding fields, use `group_concat()` like so

```
select 
    Value, 
    group_concat(
        distinct field_number 
        order by Value
    ) as fields
from table_name tn1
group by Value
order by Value
```

output:

```
Value            | fields
---------------------------------
1                | 1,2      
2                | 3,4
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4c0c/1) implemented from [this](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysqls-group_concat/) blog post