# query result in set of interval ranges in postgresql(rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a `timestamp` column for which i have to calculate the time difference and divide it into certain set of intervals

for time difference in hours i have written this query

```
 result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query("SELECT id,(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - image_retouch_items.created_at)/3600)::INTEGER AS latency FROM image_retouch_items WHERE status= 0;");
```

The result of my query is

```
"id"   "latency"
 104     5928
 106     5917
 158     5751
 162     5736
 95      5940
 85      5950
```

How to get result as set of intervals(hours),like for row for which time difference lie between the range of `0-24 hr` increment the count .
  i.e.

```
 interval    count
  0-24         2
 24-48         3
 48-72         0
```

How to get that in single query

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10607102/2640181

Comment: You can do something like this `SELECT COUNT(table_name.id)
FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2000-01-01 00:00'
                     , timestamp '2000-01-02 00:00'
                     , interval  '24 hours') t(x);`

Comment: @Vishal This doesn't work, as i have run the above query which i put in the `result ` variable, to the result which you can can see in my updated question while using this query how would I write your generate_series part