# Returning percentage according to age intervals from employees table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, percentage

I have a table employees[employee_id,age] and I wish to return the percentage of employees age between 18 and 20, and  26-40, something like:

```
Age Interval Percent
18-20          35%
26-40          40 %
```

Thanks

```
Select t.range as [age interval] , Count(*) as 'number of appereances' from
(Select case when age between 18 and 26 then '18-26'
when age between 26-40 then '26-40' end as range from employees) t
group by t.range
```

Comment: What is the query to return that, I can't figure it out

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: select age, COUNT(*) as count from employees group by age order by age, but I can't figure out how to make intervals...

Comment: Perhaps this will give you some idea:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232387/in-sql-how-can-you-group-by-in-ranges

Comment: it helped, I managed to return intervals and number but I still don't know how to calculate percentages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select '18-20',
    count(case when age between 18 and 20 then 1 end) * 100.0 / count(*)
from employees

union all 

select '26-40',
    count(case when age between 26 and 40 then 1 end) * 100.0 / count(*)
from employees
```

[SQL Fiddle Example #1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29847/9)

You could also write a slightly cleaner (easier to maintain) version like this:

```
select cast(r.Start as varchar(3)) + '-' + cast(r.[End] as varchar(3)),
    count(case when e.age between r.Start and r.[End] then 1 end) * 100.0 / (select count(*) from employees) 
from (
    select 18 as Start, 20 as [End]
    union all      
    select 21 as Start, 25 as [End]
    union all      
    select 26 as Start, 40 as [End]
) r  
left outer join employees e on e.age between r.Start and r.[End]
group by cast(r.Start as varchar(3)) + '-' + cast(r.[End] as varchar(3))
```

[SQL Fiddle Example #2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29847/18)

Answer (score 1):

You generally want to do this sort of thing with windows functions:

```
Select t.range as [age interval] , Count(*) as 'number of appereances',
       cast(count(*)*100.0/tot as varchar(256))+'%' as 'percent'
from (Select (case when age between 18 and 26 then '18-26'
                  when age between 26 and 40 then '26-40'
              end) as range,
             count(*) over (partition by NULL) as tot
      from employees) t
group by t.range
```

I also formatted the number as you have it in your example.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT

```
  SUM(CASE WHEN [dbo].[GetAge](DateOfBirth) < 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Under_20],
    SUM(CASE WHEN [dbo].[GetAge](DateOfBirth) BETWEEN 20 AND 25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Age_21_25],
    SUM(CASE WHEN [dbo].[GetAge](DateOfBirth) >=26 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Age_26_Elder]

from AspNetUsers(nolock) au inner join AspNetUserRoles(nolock) aur
on au.Id=aur.UserId inner join AspNetRoles(nolock) ar on aur.RoleId=ar.Id
Inner join StudentProfiles(nolock) st on au.Id = st.UserId
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
Select 
CAST(ROUND(count(case when 18 <= age and  age < 26 then 1 end) * 100.0 / count(*),2)AS NUMERIC(8,2)) as '18-26'
,CAST(ROUND(count(case when 26 <= age and  age < 40 then 1 end) * 100.0 / count(*),2)AS NUMERIC(8,2)) as '26-40'
From employees
```

plus obtimisée

Comment: This question already has a detailed answer. Please explain, what makes your answer a better solution and please use English only.