# how to group and count in a single query?

Tags: sql, group-by, ms-access-2007, aggregate-functions

I think it should use   GroupBy and aggregate functions to do the following steps I require, however I  just can’t get this to work:
So say I have the table below but with more records
Price

```
         Cost Zone  Zip Code    Weight(lbs) Price   Cost    Freight Value
             5       K0K             1209      0    135     289
             5       K0K             157       0    135     0
             5       K0L             1425      0    135     650
             5       K0L             1425      0    135     1999
```

I wish to require a query stating that the count of “Freight Value” falls into one of the ranges

```
          Zip Code  Range 0-500 Range 501-1000  Range 1001-2000
            K0K         2              0                  0
            K0L         0              1                  1
```

How is this possible to do this ?? if you need me to explain with more detail let me know, thank you up ahead!

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232387/in-sql-how-can-you-group-by-in-ranges

Comment: @JacobMidtgaard-Olesen That link is SQL Server. SQL is a generic tag, the particular flavour requested is MS Access.

Answer (score 1):

This will run in MS Access. You will need a range table, then:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(t1.FreightValue) AS SumFreightValue
SELECT t1.ZipCode
FROM t1, Range
WHERE (((t1.FreightValue) Between [range].[Upper] And [range].[lower]))
GROUP BY t1.ZipCode
PIVOT Range.Range
```

**Range table**

```
Range      Lower   Upper
0-500          0     500
501-1000     501    1000
1001-2000   1001    2000
```