# Select multiple values from multiple range

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In SQL, how can you “group by” in ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232387/in-sql-how-can-you-group-by-in-ranges)

i have table like that

```
price
id  |  prices
1   |   3910
2   |   4125
3   |   3740
4   |   2700
5   |   1600
6   |   2150
7   |   2430
```

my wished output is like that

```
1500-1999  |  2000-2499 | 2500-2999  | 3000-3499 | 3500-3999 | 4000-4499  |   allvalues
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1       |      2     |      1     |     0     |     2     |     1      |   7
```

expli :

- 1500-1999 --> means i want count numbers which are between 1500 and 1999
     and so on , with others.
- allvalues is to count all values .

  *here is the [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5803e/1) if someone need to test it there.

hope all is clear , thanks for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232387/in-sql-how-can-you-group-by-in-ranges will probably help you out.

Comment: The linked question is related but for a different format, with counts as a column and ranges as a column - not columns per range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a kind of pivot using ranges. The pattern is the same for a pivot query using `SUM(CASE...)`

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN prices BETWEEN 1500 AND 1999 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `1500-1999`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN prices BETWEEN 2000 AND 2499 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `2000-2499`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN prices BETWEEN 2500 AND 2999 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `2500-2999`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN prices BETWEEN 3000 AND 3499 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `3000-3499`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN prices BETWEEN 3500 AND 3999 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `3500-3999`,
  ...
  COUNT(*) AS `All Values`
FROM
  prices
```

Substitute the rest of the ranges...  The `CASE` produces a 0 or 1 if the condition is matched and those are added up by the aggregate `SUM()`s.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5803e/10

Comment: and allvalues  , it will be count(*) right ?

Comment: @goodmood Yes, sorry I missed that.