# Postgres query for 10 steps in a range

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, aggregate-functions, generate-series

We have a RAILS app with Postgres as database and have a use case for drawing a graph over a range of values. Unfortunately the range is a decimal, so I am not able to use the generate_series function of Postgres. Need help in figuring out an optimal way to query this rather than splitting this into 10 different queries. Here's sample data

- We have a table with score | students
- Given a query I would get a set of score-student tuples, from which I get range(min(score), max(score)). For example range(10.25, 16.80)
- We need to break the above range into 10 steps with an interval of 0.655 which is (max-min)10 - 10.25,10.91,11.56,12.22,12.87
- For each step above show the number of students between that score and previous value
- Result would be an array with [(10.25,11232),(10.91,2434),....]

Any way/thoughts to do this in Postgres in a single query or less than 10+ queries?

Comment: Maybe you should try to adapt this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232387/in-sql-how-can-you-group-by-in-ranges

Comment: Nice, thanks for the pointer @RubyRacer

Comment: The question should provide a table definition, your version of Postgres, some sample values and the query you tried (even if it's not working). Ideally an sql fiddle ([random example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bc7d7/3)).

Comment: Also, why do you want an array as result instead of a result set?

Comment: Huh. I never noticed there wasn't a `generate_series` for `numeric`. I'll point it out on pgsql-hackers; it'd be a good newbie developer task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result as **set** (makes more sense to me):

```
WITH base AS (
   SELECT student, score
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  <some_condition>
   )
, border AS (
   SELECT min(score) AS min_score, max(score) AS max_score
   FROM   base
   )
SELECT lower_bound, ct
FROM  (
   SELECT step
        , min_score + ((max_score - min_score) * (step-1)) / 10 AS lower_bound
   FROM   border, generate_series(1,10) step
   ) x
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT width_bucket(b.score, x.min_score, x.max_score, 10) AS step
        , count(*)::int AS ct
   FROM   border x, base b
   GROUP  BY step
   ) y USING (step)
ORDER  BY step;
```

Featuring two [CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html), [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html) (still useful) and the often overlooked function [width_bucket()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html).

To produce an **array of composite types**, like outlined in the question, first create a matching type (once):

```
CREATE TYPE my_type AS (bound numeric, ct int);
```

Assuming [`numeric`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) values for lack of information.
Then feed above query to an [array constructor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS):

```
SELECT ARRAY (
   <query from above>
   SELECT (lower_bound, ct::int)::my_type   -- only difference
   <query from above>
   );
```

Comment: @erwin-brandsetter, thanks for the detailed answer and apologies for missing postgres version and sqlfiddle (wasn't aware). I am on 9.3 so have access to the functions you mentioned. width_bucket() seems the right tool for my use case. With your answer I am able to get what I want. I also ran into http://tapoueh.org/blog/2014/02/21-PostgreSQL-histogram, which helped some more.