# SQL Group rows together based on specified Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to group rows together based on a set value. so I have a query that has 100 rows I would like to group them by every 10 rows and assign a number starting with 1.

So

First 10 rows would be assigned 1, next 10 get 2 next 10 get 3 and so on.

I have tried working this out with row_number, rank etc but not been able to do it.

is this possible?

Cheers
Patrick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In SQL, how can you "group by" in ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232387/in-sql-how-can-you-group-by-in-ranges)

Answer (score 2):

Based on ROW_NUMBER and integer division:

```
(Row_Number () Over (ORDER BY whatever) -1) / 10 + 1
```