# mysql LEFT JOIN followed by GROUP BY with BETWEEN Ranges

Tags: mysql

I am stumped with how I should proceed. Here is my current LEFT JOIN command which works just fine:

```
SELECT t1.avg_temperature as T_aver,
       t2.new_confirmed as count 
FROM 3_day_avg as t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 on t1.date = t2.date
```

And this works great to make this table:

```
T_aver    |count|
-----------------
-0.2      | 2   |
3         | 2   |
5         | 1   |
-2.3      | 4   |
22        | 0   |
```

But now I want to take it one step further and group by ranges of T_aver (bins like 0-5, 6-10, 11-15, etc) and SUM() the count column. For example, If I was to place the range on the LEFT JOIN table example above of -10 to 0, and 0 to 30, the final table would look like this:

```
Trange    |count|
-----------------
-10 - 0   | 6   |
0 - 30    | 3   |
```

This above transformation is where I am stumped and I fear to make my life simpler I just need to create one big table instead...

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you search group by range, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/233223/2996989) or you dont have defined bins ,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In SQL, how can you "group by" in ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232387/in-sql-how-can-you-group-by-in-ranges)

Comment: Have you attempted anything on binning those data?  Your query there doesn't show any binning code.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close! Just start with your existing query and then wrap it.

For your bins use another lookup table if you don't want to be bound to a fixed interval:

**bins:**

```
mintemp | maxtemp
 -10    | 0
   0    | 30
```

I will use `num` instead of `count`, as I never use reserved words as columns:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(mintemp, ' - ', maxtemp) AS Trange,
  SUM(baseview.num) AS num
FROM bins
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    t1.avg_temperature as T_aver,
    t2.new_confirmed as num
  FROM 3_day_avg as t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 on t1.date = t2.date
  ) AS baseview
ON baseview.T_aver>bins.mintemp AND baseview.T_aver<=bins.maxtemp
GROUP BY bins.mintemp;
```

Comment: I am trying your answer and I get this as the error; Unknown column 'baseview.mintemp' in 'group statement'

Comment: Good catch: Typo in the GROUP BY ... fixed it.

Comment: It actually needs to be GROUP BY Trange ... for me that worked flawlessly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ranges.caption Trange,
       SUM(t2.new_confirmed) as `count` 
FROM 3_day_avg as t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 on t1.date = t2.date
JOIN ( SELECT -10 t_from, 0 t_to, '-10 - 0' caption 
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 0, 30, '0 - 30' ) ranges ON t1.avg_temperature >= ranges.t_from 
                                      AND t1.avg_temperature < ranges.t_to 
GROUP BY ranges.caption;
```

It is better to create static `ranges` table instead of dynamically generated. This allows to create and to store a lot of pre-defined sets of ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by a `CASE` expression which contains your bins:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN t1.avg_temperature >= -10 and t1.avg_temperature <= 0 THEN '-10 - 0'
    WHEN t1.avg_temperature > 0 and t1.avg_temperature <=30 THEN '0 - 30'
  END AS Trange,
  SUM(t2.new_confirmed) AS count 
FROM 3_day_avg AS t1 LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 
ON t1.date = t2.date
GROUP BY Trange
```

You may add more bins in the `CASE` expression, change the ranges and the inequality signs to suit your requirement.