# How to do a range aggregation when ranges overlap?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count, range

Suppose I have table with a numeric column called `score`.

```
 id  | score 
-----+-------
   1 |   817
   2 |    57
   3 |   571
   4 |   906
   5 |   496
   6 |   129
   7 |    93
 ... |  ...
```

In standard SQL or Postgresql, how to produce a table of counts by range with these ranges **overlapping** ?

```
score_range | count 
-------------+-------
 0-20        |     9
 15-50       |    25
 25-*        |   597
```

[The `case when`solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232387/in-sql-how-can-you-group-by-in-ranges/236314) is inapplicable here as it only returns the first bucket the score belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a derived table to define the ranges.  Then `left join` and `group by`:

```
select v.range, count(t.score)
from (values  ('0-20', 0, 20),
              ('15-50', 15, 50),
              ('25-*', 25, null)
     ) v(range, lo, hi) left join
     t 
     on t.score >= v.lo and (t.score <= v.hi or v.hi is null)
group by v.range
order by v.lo;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Postgres' range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/rangetypes.html) for this, along with the containment operator (`@>`):

```
select r.score_range, count(*)
from (values 
    ('0-20', '[0, 20]'::int4range), 
    ('15-50', '[15, 50]'::int4range), 
    ('25-*', '[25,]'::int4range)
) r(score_range, rg)
left join mytable t on r.rg @> t.score
group by r.score_range
```

`'[0, 20]'::int4range` represents a range of integers for `0` (inclusive) to `20` (inclusive). `'[25,]'::int4range` represents a range from `25` (inclusive) to infinity. If you want exclusive ranges, you can use parentheses (`()`) instead of square brackets (`[]`).